# Split long table into visual columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend

Right now I have a simple table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>char</td>
    <td>XXX</td>
  <tr>
  ... and so
</table>
```

That visually renders like:

```
| Char   | XXX    |
| Char   | XXX    |
| Char   | XXX    |
| Char   | XXX    |
| Char   | XXX    |
| Char   | XXX    |
| Char   | XXX    |
| Char   | XXX    |
```

But because of my design, I need to render like (and being responsive, i use bootstrap btw):

```
| Char   | XXX    | | Char   | XXX    |
| Char   | XXX    | | Char   | XXX    |
| Char   | XXX    | | Char   | XXX    |
| Char   | XXX    | | Char   | XXX    |
```

The table is created dynamically from a DB, so I have no control to define 4 columns in my table, I need something that works like style="column-count: 2;"

any idea??

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple tables by using float style like:

```
<table border="2" style="float:left">
<tr><td>  Date  </td><td>  Day  </td><td>  In time  </td><td>  Out time  </td><td>  Signature  </td></tr>
<tr><td>01-Mar </td><td>Tue</td><td>  </td><td>  </td><td>    </td></tr>
<tr><td>02-Mar </td><td>Wed</td><td>  </td><td>  </td><td>    </td></tr>
</table>
<table border="2"><tr>
<tr><td>  Date  </td><td>  Day  </td><td>  In time  </td><td>  Out time  </td><td>  Signature  </td></tr>
<tr><td>16-Mar </td><td>Wed</td><td>  </td><td>  </td><td>    </td></tr>
<tr><td>17-Mar </td><td>Thu</td><td>  </td><td>  </td><td>    </td></tr>
</table>
```